# Grafico SVG, con javascript embebido, utilizo getElementById() no funciona correctamente en IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, svg

Deseo modificar o ver algunos valores cuando me centro en un elemento de un dibujo SVG. Esto funciona correctamente en Chrome y Firefox. Pero cuando se utiliza IE11, no funciona. ¿Cuál podría ser la causa? ¿Hay algunas bibliotecas JS que resuelven estas incompatibilidades entre navegadores?

El código HTML en la página es:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="Imagen/SVG-STO.svg" style="width: 175px; height: 258px"></object>
    </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

El código SVG es:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="hexMap" viewBox="18 281 175 259" width="175" height="259" xml:space="preserve" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    var objNames =  
    {
      "AA":{"name":"Hex A","value":"965787"},
      "BB":{"name":"Hex B","value":"48986"}
    };
     
    function m_over(hover_id) { 
      var objName = objNames[hover_id].name;
      var objValue = objNames[hover_id].value;
      document.getElementById("Nombre").innerHTML = objName;
      document.getElementById("Valor").innerHTML = objValue;
      document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity","0.3");
    }
    function m_out(hover_id)   {
      document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1.0");
      console.log(hover_id);
      document.getElementById("Nombre").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("Valor").innerHTML = "";
    }
     
    ]]>
    </script>
    <text id = "Nombre" x = "28.74" y = "301" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Initial</text>
    <text id = "Valor" x = "28.74" y = "321" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Value</text>             
    <path id="AA" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#00A600;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,326l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>     
    <path id="BB" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#19AF00;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,356l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>
</svg>
```

En Firefox y Chrome la imagen que se muestra es:

[image: Imagen con valores correcto]

En IE11 faltan los valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que tener en cuenta algo importante: aunque SVG parezca HTML porque tiene una notación parecida, realmente no es HTML.

En SVG no existe `innerHTML`, algunos navegadores pueden interpretarlo correctamente porque interpretan el SVG *inline* como si fuera HTML, pero realmente no es lo "adecuado". Lo correcto en SVG sería usar [`textContent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement).

Cambia los `innerHTML` por `textContent` para modificar el texto de los `text` y  ya funciona en IE:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="hexMap" viewBox="18 281 175 259" width="175" height="259" xml:space="preserve" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    var objNames =  
    {
      "AA":{"name":"Hex A","value":"965787"},
      "BB":{"name":"Hex B","value":"48986"}
    };
     
    function m_over(hover_id) { 
      var objName = objNames[hover_id].name;
      var objValue = objNames[hover_id].value;
      document.getElementById("Nombre").textContent = objName;
      document.getElementById("Valor").textContent = objValue;
      document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity","0.3");
    }
    function m_out(hover_id)   {
      document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1.0");
      console.log(hover_id);
      document.getElementById("Nombre").textContent = "";
      document.getElementById("Valor").textContent = "";
    }
     
    ]]>
    </script>
    <text id = "Nombre" x = "28.74" y = "301" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Initial</text>
    <text id = "Valor" x = "28.74" y = "321" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Value</text>             
    <path id="AA" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#00A600;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,326l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>     
    <path id="BB" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#19AF00;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,356l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Alvaro, excelente tu respuesta, funciona Ok.